# How to expand a div from an icon

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a div with a nested icon and other hidden text

```
<div>
    <span class="hidden">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span class="hidden">Dolor Sit Amet</span>
    <img src="icon.svg" />
</div>
```

The initial size of the div is equal to the icon and when the icon's hovered, the spans should be visible and the div should expand to fit the size of the content.

[image: div scheme]

#### The Hover Area isn't defined by another div, it's defined by the size of the content inside the div

I know how to do this, the problem is to animate the widening of the div.

## EDIT: I DON'T HAVE ANY VALUES FOR THE DIV ENDING DIMENSIONS

## EDIT 2: HERE IS THE SNIPPET WHICH EVERYONE WAS WAITING FOR

```css
:root {
 --nero: #1C0904;
 --marrone: #843A26;
 --arancione: #F25B1A;
 --giallo: #F49F0A;
 --bianco: #F2F2F2;
 
 --icon-size: 36px;
}

.home-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

.home-section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.centered {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.contact-menu {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

.contact-menu-wrapper {
 padding-right: 12px;
}

.contact-menu-img {
 height: var(--icon-size);
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-menu-item {
 margin: 20px 0;
 overflow: auto;
}

.contact-menu-call-box {
 width: var(--icon-size);
 height: var(--icon-size);
 border-radius: calc(var(--icon-size) / 2);
 background: var(--marrone);
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: .5s;
}

.contact-menu-call-box a {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 opacity: 1;
 display: block;
 color: var(--bianco);
 white-space: nowrap;
 transition: .5s;
}

.contact-menu-call-box:hover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-right: var(--icon-size);
 transition: .5s;
}

.contact-menu-call-box:hover a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: .5s;
}

.contact-menu-call-box img {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="contact-menu centered">
 <div class="contact-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="contact-menu-item">
   <div class="contact-menu-call-box">
    <a href="tel:1234567890">123 456 7890</a>
    <a href="tel:0987654321">098 765 4321</a>
    <img class="contact-menu-img" src="http://vivoda.ga/img/icons/phone.svg" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-menu-item">
   <img class="contact-menu-img" src="http://vivoda.ga/img/icons/mail.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="contact-menu-item">
   <img class="contact-menu-img" src="http://vivoda.ga/img/icons/location.svg" />
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code, Simone?

Comment: It's an entire website and there are lots of classes only for that portion of site. But, if you really wish, here is the [github repo](https://github.com/simonebroili/Vivoda).

Comment: @isherwood I tried to minimise it but it doesn't seem to act the same way as the website does.

Comment: @isherwood I updated with the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this with basic CSS Transitions. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1) example.

something like this

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
}

section{
background: black;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
transition: width 2s, height 2s;}

section:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The transition Property</h1>

<p>Hover over the div element below, to see the transition effect:</p>
<div>
<section>
</section>
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm already using them, but the width works while the height isn't affected by the animation.

Comment: See my updated response for a full explanation of how to do height and width.

Comment: Thank you for being so kind, but what I'm asking is that I have a initial width and height and animate to 100% of the inside content, not specified values.

Comment: I see, okay I have updated it again. I think that is more of what you are asking for?

Comment: Evidently I wasn't totally clear. I don't have any box which expand the div to, but I have the div and some content, when I hover on the icon, the content should be visible and the div should resize to fit the inner content and not the size of the icon anymore (see the drawing in the question).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-create what you're asking using some other CSS properties, transitioning the `max-width` CSS property:

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="hidden">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span class="hidden">Dolor Sit Amet</span>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKbCl.png" />
</div>
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}

div.container:hover .hidden {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AskYous/p59of4sd/25/)

Comment: If you read a little better, you would have understood that I know how to do that and what I'm struggling with are the transitions.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't see that last sentence. Updated my answer. Should work now.

Comment: Nice idea to expand the inner elements instead of the outer one, but I don't know why it doesn't work on my website

Comment: Make sure the `.hidden` elements are displayed as `inline-block`, as well as the div holding them.

Comment: You have to share something. There's no way to know what the error is unless you give us something of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
 transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

div:hover {
  display: inline;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```